# File explorer not opening after upgrade to 12.04 and other issues

Tags: upgrade, nautilus, themes, filemanager

Recently I upgraded Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 via Update manager. But I face many problems.
1. The File Explorer is not at all opening.
2. All my files that were in Desktop are missing. And couldn't open File explorer.
3. My Ubuntu theme (default) has become fully corrupted and very ugly.

Please solve my problems.

Comment: Run a live cd/usb and back up all you valuable data.Try to do as many thing you can to recover it to its old position.Restart your ubuntu system and run the "recovery mode" and fix "broken issues" and come back to normal mode and see any changes.If nothing works think about a frsh installation.

Answer (score 0):

All your files are there, they are just not visible on the desktop. They will be in ~/Desktop but since you can't open the file manager, you obviously can't find them. Try creating another user and logging in fresh with the new user. Set the new user up as ADMIN if possible so that you can gain access to the old profile and see your files. Then what you may want to do after your calm after you've confirmed that your files are still there, is repair your profile, so that everything works and you can use the filemanager and enable DESKTOP icons again. You might have to delete your .config folder and let ubuntu recreate it.